# redirecting shell command output to C program

Tags: c, shell, io-redirection

I have the following program :

```
/* a.c */ 
#include <stdio.h>

int   
main(int argc, char* argv[]){     

size_t size=0;    
char* lineptr;      

    while(getline(&lineptr, &size, stdin)){           
        fprintf(stderr, "line = %s\n", lineptr);      
        if(lineptr){      
            free(lineptr);     
            lineptr = NULL;     
        }      
    }      

return 0;      
}
```

I redirected the output of shell command "ls" to this program using the
following line :

```
ls | ./a.out
```

Expected output :
program should print the name of all files in the current directory
and terminate.

Actual output :
The program prints the name of all the files but does not terminate,
instead it loops infinitely and prints the last entry infinitely.

Thanks

Comment: Did you read the manual for `getline`?

Comment: I was ignoring the return value of getline. at the end it returns -1 which happens to be a true value, thus the infinite loop.

Comment: Since you aren't using the arguments, you'd do better to be explicit about that and write `int main(void)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GNU's `getline` function returns `-1` upon end-of-file (or error). Use

```
while(-1 != getline(&lineptr, &size, stdin))
```

...and set `lineptr` to `NULL` before the first call to `getline`.

Also, you don't have to `free` the pointer in every iteration of the loop; you can reuse the previous pointer and `free` once at the end:

```
size_t size = 0;
char* lineptr = NULL;

while(-1 != getline(&lineptr, &size, stdin)){
  fprintf(stderr, "line = %s", lineptr);
}

free(lineptr);
```

`getline` will use `realloc` internally as needed. Note that you have to make sure that `lineptr` and `size` are not changed between calls to `getline` for this to work (although you may change the string to which `lineptr` points).

Comment: I read the manual, it says if lineptr is NULL, then the value of size is ignored, so i made lineptr to be NULL after every iteration

Comment: That works, but it is inefficient. There is no need to do a heap allocation every iteration, only when the allocated space is too small and has to be enlarged. `getline` handles this internally, so there's no need not to take advantage of it.